# Presenting UIView similar to UIAlertView in SplitviewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uiview, uisplitviewcontroller

I am using SplitViewController. Now i want to present a UIView similar to UIAlertView when i select a row in detail view controller.

I have tried presenting the view like this,

```
[self presentModalViewController:view animated:YES];
```

but my view is getting loaded from the bottom. So can anyone give me some suggestion or sample to achieve this.

Also i want to increase my master view width. I tried to change the size in pop over but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your view as a subview to the (split-)viewcontrollers view

```
[splitViewController.view addSubview: yourView];
```

You can set your views background color to clearColor and create another view on it to make it look like a smaller view in the middle of the screen.

Comment: if i add subview means it will cover my detail screen alone. But i want it to cover the complete screen as UIAlertView appears.

Comment: You're right. Can you add it to splitViewController.view? Sorry overlooked the split view and don't use it so much but I would think it also has a view property.

Comment: Yeah there is a property so we can add it to spliltViewController.view. For that animation i just used UIView beginanimations. now it works fine.